# selenium with C# on IE

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium

Switching multiple windows in IE.

First page has LOGIN button which on clicked goes to second window.

Second window takes credentials and has a NEXT button which on clicked goes to      third window.

Third window has a button which on clicking moves to the fourth window.

How do I navigate mutiple windows using Selenium with C#.My website runs on IE only.

Answer (score 1):

To switch to the new window after it opens you can use

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```